# Spring Cloud Stream: how to pass deployment properties to specific applications when they have identical names

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Simple example from app starters:

```
stream create --name fileTofile --definition 'file --file.directory=./input | file --file.directory=./output'
```

Next, when deploying the stream I would like to override "file.directory" property for one of the apps. How do I distinguish between the apps with the same name, when passing a deployment property?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `label` for the app when creating the stream in the DSL. and refer the label when specifying the deployment properties.

In your case,

`stream create --name fileTofile --definition 'source-file:file --file.directory=./input | sink-file:file --file.directory=./output'`

You can refer the doc for it [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-labels)

Comment: And what will happen in my case , if I just pass app.file.file.directory deployment property (when I have 2 apps with the same name and no labels)?

Comment: You will get an error as: dataflow:>stream create --name fileTofile --definition 'file --file.directory=./input | file --file.directory=./output'
Command failed org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowClientException: 143E:(pos 32): label 'file' should be unique but app 'file' (at position 0) and app 'file' (at position 1) both use it
file --file.directory=./input | file --file.directory=./output
                                ^